# findstr: search strings too long

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting, findstr

I am trying to compare a list of IP's and output the difference by using the findstr command in Windows and am having difficulty getting it to work. The command I am using is:

EDIT: My objective is to compare IP's that were scanned successfully to IP's that were scanned successfully with authentication achieved and output it the files that aren't in **IPsSuccessfullyScannedwithAuthentication.txt** but are in **IPsSuccessfullyScanned.txt** to **IPsSuccessfullyScannedButNotAuthenticated.txt**.

Let's say **IPsSuccessfullyScanned.txt** contain

> 192.168.0.1
>
> 192.168.0.2
>
> 192.168.0.3
>
> 192.168.0.4
>
> 192.168.0.5
>
> 192.168.0.6
>
> 192.168.0.7
>
> 192.168.0.8-192.168.0.12

and **IPsSuccessfullyScannedwithAuthentication.txt** (which are the IP's that authenticated and were successfully scanned) contain

> 192.168.0.1
>
> 192.168.0.2
>
> 192.168.0.3
>
> 192.168.0.4
>
> 192.168.0.6
>
> 192.168.0.8-192.168.0.10
>
> 192.168.0.12

My **IPsSuccessfullyScannedButNotAuthenticated.txt** should have this:

> 192.168.0.5
>
> 192.168.0.7
>
> 192.168.0.11

**findstr /vixg:IPsSuccessfullyScanned.txt IPsSuccessfullyScannedwithAuthentication.txt > IPsSuccessfullyScannedButNotAuthenticated.txt**

What I am trying to achieve is very similar to this post:

[.bat file to compare two text files and output the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045754/bat-file-to-compare-two-text-files-and-output-the-difference)

Here is my issue though, the file size in the IPs2.txt is 720 bytes. 
When I researched about the findstr command, I found out that when doing a regular expression search, the maximum search string length is 254 bytes. A regular expression with length between 255 bytes and 511 bytes will result in a FINDSTR: Out of memory error with ERRORLEVEL 2.

A regular expression length >511 bytes results in the **FINDSTR: Search string too long. error.** **(which is the error I'm currently getting)**.

My question is: What alternatives are out there that I can use to be able to compare the two text files? If there are any other suggestions to resolve my issue as easy as possible, even a bat file can help if possible.

References:

http://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html

[What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: Excuse me, but your question is not clear. What do you want as result? The lines in IPs2.txt that does not exist in IPs1.txt? Vice versa? Both? Other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35090416.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q35090416_2.txt"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: Read first file into memory
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" "%filename1%"') DO SET "$%%a=%%b"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 SET "same="
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('SET $ 2^>nul') DO (
  IF /i "%%a"=="%%c" SET "same=y"
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED same ECHO(%%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `filename*` to suit your circumstances.

I used files named `q35090416*.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

The report produced by this routine is lines contained in the second file that are not contained in the first, which appears to be the object of your `findstr /vixg` command. Please explain clearly what you are wttempting to do - we can't fix something that doesn't work if we don't know precisely what the object is.

The routine may have problems if any string starts `]` or with any of the usual problems encountered with batch string-processing.

---

Your edits have changed the problem radically. The issue has much to do with the **content** of the files. The limit of 254 characters for `findstr` is a limit **per line**, not of the file overall.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35090416.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q35090416_2.txt"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: Read first file into memory
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=-" %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 IF "%%b"=="" (SET "$%%a=Y") ELSE (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-4,8delims=." %%p IN ("%%a.%%b") DO FOR /l %%x IN (%%s,1,%%t) DO SET "$%%p.%%q.%%r.%%x=y"
 )
)
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=-" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%b"=="" (IF NOT DEFINED $%%a ECHO %%a) ELSE (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-4,8delims=." %%p IN ("%%a.%%b") DO FOR /l %%x IN (%%s,1,%%t) DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED $%%p.%%q.%%r.%%x ECHO %%p.%%q.%%r.%%x
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This solution should fit. I use filenames for testing that correspond to the SO question number so that I can revisit the problem if required. Hence filename1 here is your successfully-scanned list, filename2 is the authenticated list and the output is the difference.

You could enclose the **entire** second `for` statement in parentheses to  redirect the output to a file if you wish, ie.

```
...
for ....
)
...
```

becomes

```
...
(
for ....
)
)>somefilename
...
```

to redirect the output to `somefilename`

The routine works by first removing all environment variables that start with `$` (normally there are none, but that makes sure)

Then it examines the second file, splitting the line into `%%a` and `%%b` (the two tokens either side of the delimiter "-")
If the second token does not exist, then it sets an environment variable eg "$192.168.0.1". If it does exist then it re-tokenises "%%a.%%b" (note `.`) and assigns the 1-4 and 8th token, so "192.168.0.8-192.168.0.10" becomes "192.168.0.8" and "192.168.0.10"; this is pot together as "**192**.**168**.**0**.**8**.192.168.0.**10**" and the tokens `192,168,0,8 and 10` are assigned to `%%p..%%t`. The `for /l` loop then assigns a value to `$192.168.0.8` through to `$192.168.0.10`

Next is a similar story, but this time the routine simply checks whether the variable is set. If it isn't set, then the number is `echo`ed.

Comment: I edited my post, please let me know if you think your bat file should still work to my needs. When I ran the bat file with the sample data I wrote above, it doesn't give the expected result. I suppose because they're comparing literal strings together. When it comes to IP's they sometimes put "-" between IP's to shorten the length in the program I am using. Is there a way for a batch file to tell which number is missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "d="
< input1.txt (
   for /F "tokens=1-4,8 delims=.-" %%a in (input2.txt) do (
      if "%%e" equ "" (set "n=%%d") else set "n=%%e"
      for /L %%i in (%%d,1,!n!) do call :check %%a.%%b.%%c.%%i
   )
) > result.txt
goto :EOF


:check
   if not defined d (
      set "line="
      set /P "line="
      if not defined line exit /B
      for /F "tokens=1-4,8 delims=.-" %%A in ("!line!") do (
         set "abc=%%A.%%B.%%C"
         set "i=%%D"
         set "d=%%E"
      )
   ) else (
      set /A i+=1
      if !i! equ !d! set "d="
   )
   if "%abc%.%i%" equ "%1" exit /B
   echo %abc%.%i%
goto check
```

`input1.txt` file is the larger one (with `192.168.0.5` and `192.168.0.7` IP's), and `input2.txt` the shorter one, without such IP's. Output example:

```
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.11
```